# Downloading jpg,doc,ppt files with php are corrupted

Tags: php, mime-types, content-type

i am trying to download some files with php to hide the filepath but some filetypes are always broken.
Filetypes like pdf and mp3 works great.
Filetypes like doc, ppt, jpg always downloads broken.

i use these mimetypes

```
if (file_exists($file_real)){ 
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, "."), 1)); 
switch($extension){ 
case "ppt": $type = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break; 
case "pdf": $type = "application/pdf"; break; //------ok
case "doc": $type = "application/msword"; break; 
case "mp3": $type = "audio/mpeg"; break;//------ok
case "jpg": $type = "image/jpg"; break;  
default: $type = "application/force-download"; break; 
}
```

and these headers

```
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: public", false); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: " . $type); 
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $header_file . "\";"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_real));
if ($stream = fopen($file_real, 'rb')){
            while(!feof($stream) && connection_status() == 0){
                set_time_limit(0);
                print(fread($stream,1024*8));
                flush();
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
```

Comment: Are you downloading PPT/DOC or PPTX/DOCX? DocX content type is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" and  PPTX is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"

Comment: What way are you opening and outputting the files?

Comment: Doc files created with word2003 and powerpoint files with powerpoint2003.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're outputting white-space characters in your PHP code. Probably line feeds. This is a very common cause of file corruption when serving binary files via PHP, and can be hard to spot. It is also very typical of cases where some file types are corrupted and others aren't, because some file types can cope with the extra white space.

White space can creep into a PHP program very easily, simply by having line feeds in your source code outside of the `<?php` and `?>` markers.

Check your PHP program - and all your includes - to ensure they don't have any trailing blank lines after the closing `?>` at the end of the program. Also check at the top of the files before the `<?php` marker, but blank lines at the end of the program is much more common.

In fact, better to remove the `?>` end marker entirely -- it is optional anyway, and removing it means you definitely won't have any white space issues at the end of your PHP files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tested. Removed ?> kai clear white spaces, but still the same problem.

Comment: Have you done a byte-comparison of the original file compared with the downloaded copy? That might well give you a clue as to what it is.

Comment: The downloaded doc file has 66.051bytes and the original 66.045bytes

Comment: @Allos can you compare the files and see what those six bytes are? Are they spaces or white space at the start or end of the file? Or are they some other kind of corruption? If the former, then you need to look further for white space in your code. If something else, then the problem is more complex; I can't see anything in the code that would do that though.

Comment: I have faced similar issues and the solution was through ensuring that there are no other outputs given by the file aside `readfile()` function... for anyone facing a similar issue check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75934495/7316214)