# Downloading 'blob' type file from database with PHP. Files are corrupted, unable to see the files' content

Tags: php, download, blob

I try to use this code to download files from my database, however, when I try to open the file, I get following errors:

when downloading file type 'docx':
[image]

Word documents are stored with the type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' (not visible on the screenshot). I believe this is correct

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the bug when trying a bit different code:
[Downloading jpg,doc,ppt files with php are corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864998/downloading-jpg-doc-ppt-files-with-php-are-corrupted)