# Corrupted Downloaded Files (pdf, xls, doc, ppt) PHP

Tags: php, download

I have multiple files (doc, ppt, pdf, xls) stored on a server and the user can download them through `PHP` script upon clicking a button. The file upload process is more than perfect as files are uploaded correctly without any issues such as corruption and I am even able to browse and view them on the server. Hence, the issue is with the downloading process.

Once any of those files is downloaded the fie size almost similar to the original one but with minor differences in kb (i.e. original size 694kb, downloaded 693kb).

I have browsed online including other questions and even asked CatGPT for code and references but still received the same error. Kindly find the download code snippet below.

```
header('Pragma: public');
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: {$contentType}");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$fileName}\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
set_time_limit(0);
readfile($filePath);
```

To specify the content type I have used an array with file formats to select the appropriate content type accordingly, as follows.

```
$app_type = ['pdf' => 'application/pdf', 'doc' => 'application/msword', 'docx' => 'application/msword', 'xls' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'ppt' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', 'pptx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'];
```

An example of the `filename` variable could be `thisfile.pdf`.

Been struggling with this for sometime as I have tried various methods, I appreciate your time and support. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked inside the downloaded files (e.g. with notepad++ or something) and compared them with the originals? You might find there's a bit of stray space or text or something from your PHP file (outside the PHP block), or hidden BOM character or something which is corrupting the output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ADyson insightful, when comparing I noticed a timestamp along with the document name and extension added at the beginning of the file. also, the last 3-4 lines were not completed as if it they were cut off. Not sure why this is happening considering that I have sat a time limit which should give enough time for the document to be downloaded perhaps. Any idea how can I investigate further or what to do from here?

Comment: Something else in your code is outputting the extra text, the length of the response is now longer than what `Content-Length:` specifies, and is truncated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to thank @ADyson & @Sammitch for their comments, recommendation, and enlightenment.

I was able to resolve the issue by inspecting and comparing the downloaded files using an editor (i.e. NotePad++, Notepad, sublime, etc.) in my case I have used Notepad and I have noticed additional details in the file prior to the file content and noticed missing lines at the end of the file which have caused the downloaded files to be damaged.

After further investigation, I can safely say that the `PHP` file that contains the download function was `echo`ing other text, which is considered as an output and it was printed directly along with the content of the downloaded file. As the file content is being passed from the server to the client side through the `readfile` function and any other information that is being outputted by the `PHP` file shall be shown and taken into consideration once downloading the file.

A simple way to understand it, try and create a `PHP` file that uses `readfile` function and inspect its content, now try to `echo` something or output anything from the same file.

Thank you and hope that helped and saved someone's time.